# On an asymptotic limit problem.

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Given monotone growing positive function $f(m)$ what is the slowest growing  $g(m)$ we need such that
$$\Big(1-\Big(1  -  \Big(1-\frac1{f(m)}\Big)^\binom{m}{t}\Big)^\frac mt   \Big)^{g(m)}$$ decays to $0$ as $m>0$ grows when $t=o(\log m)$ holds?